# Why group_by does not working with max(colSums) in dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tidyr

I want to know for each country, the maximum sum of duration of primary,middle and high school(because for each year, the duration may not be the same). I firstly group_by country, and the use colSum, but the value I got was the max(colSum) for all, which means the group_bu does not work here at all.

I did some research and I have detached 'plyr'. Actually, if I try

```
df1 <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  summarise(
    newvar = sum(wt)
  )
```

it works well. But here I am not mutate not on one column, but on many columns, Do you know what should I do to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

```
 data1 = data.frame(country = c("A",'A',"A",'A',"B","B","B","B"),
    item = c("Age for primary school","Duration for primary school", "Duration for middle school", "duration for high school",
             "Age for primary school","Duration for primary school", "Duration for middle school", "duration for high school"), 
                     '2008' = c(6, 6, 4, 3,7,5,4,3),  
                     '2009' = c(6, 6, 4, 3,6,6,4,3), 
                     '2010' = c(7, 5, 4, 3,6,6,4,3),  
                     '2011' = c(7, 5, 4, 3,7,5,4,3)) 
  temp1 <- dplyr::filter(data1, item != 'Age for primary school') %>%
    dplyr::group_by(country) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(n_grade = max(colSums(.[,-c(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: Have you tried `summarise_at` or `summarise_all`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.` in mutate, it will take the left-hand side of the pipe, which is the entire data.frame/tibble, not the individual groups. You can use `do` instead.

```
temp1 <- dplyr::filter(data1, item != 'Age for primary school') %>%
            dplyr::group_by(country) %>%
            dplyr::do(mutate(., n_grade = max(colSums(.[,-c(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE))))
```

As a side-note, this is how you might do it with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
temp1 <- 
data1[item != 'Age for primary school'] %>% 
    .[, n_grade := max(colSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE))
      , by = country
      , .SDcols = -(1:2)]
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks a lot. But would you please explain why after adding do(), the group_by works?

Comment: There is documentation at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/do.html . The documentation says the `...` argument to `do` is "Expressions to apply to each group." and " You can use `.` to refer to the current group". This is in contrast to how `.` is used in any other pipe operation, which is to refer to the object on the left-hand side (and not some subset of it).